# Callback function is not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, callback

I have read a few articles regarding callback function. I understand how they presented like add a + b then give callback function. But I am doing same. I first declared the function then call it again I call the callback function, why it is not working in my case?

```js
function me(callback){
  console.log("1")
}
me(function(){ 
  console.log(2)
})
```

I am expecting console.log 1 then console.log 2. I am getting only console.log 1

Comment: *"I call the callback function"* – Uhm… where?!

Comment: You did not call the `callback()`.

Comment: call the callback after console.log(1); using callback();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are calling the `callback` function, it won't trigger automatically, that approach is so you can notify something using that callback function when your function ended something.

```js
function me(callback) {
  console.log("1")

  // your process ended, lets notify
  callback();
}
me(function() {
  console.log(2)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to actually *call* the callback function inside the function it is passed to as argument:

```js
function me(callback){
  console.log(1)
  callback();
}

me(function(){ 
  console.log(2);
})
```